# Получение актуального состояния одного слайса при работе с другим - Redux Toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, slice

Я относительно новичок в Redux Toolkit, и решение этой проблемы нигде найти н могу.
Разрабатываю приложение для прохождения тестов, имею два слайса - `testSlice` (хранит состояние текущего теста) и `resultsSlice` (результаты всех тестов). Объединить слайсы нельзя, я использую redux-persist для работы с localStorage и сохраняю только общие результаты.

Суть проблемы: Нет доступа к актуальному состоянию сразу после того, как метод отработал. `testSlice` реализует метод `addToCurrentResult()` - добавляет ответ на вопрос в массив результатов *текущего* теста. Затем, если вопрос последний, отрабатывает метод `addToResults()` из слайса `resultsSlice`, который принимает состояние `testSlice` и создаёт на его основе объект результата теста. Далее добавляет его в массив результатов *всех тестов* (либо меняет, если тест пройден заново).

В коде происходит вызов двух диспатчей этих методов подряд и в общем массиве не хватает ответа на последний вопрос. (4 вопроса - ожидается массив из 4-х элементов, но приходит из 3-х)

Вроде обычное действие, и кажется можно решить с помощью extraReducers, но объяснений мало, все используют примитивные типы данных для примера.

Компонент:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Answer from "../Answer/Answer";
import styles from "./AnswerList.module.css";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { nextQuestion, addToCurrentResult } from "../../store/slices/testSlice";
import { addToResults } from "../../store/slices/resultsSlice";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import NextQuestionBtn from "../UI/NextQuestionBtn/NextQuestionBtn";

const AnswerList = (props) => {
   const {
      testId,
      answers,
      questionAmount,
      currentQuestionIndex,
      correctAnswerIndex,
   } = props;

   const dispatch = useDispatch();
   const navigate = useNavigate();

   const [selectedAnswerIndex, setSelectedAnswerIndex] = useState(null);
   const currentTest = useSelector((state) => state.test.currentTest);
   const currentResult = useSelector((state) => state.test.currentResult);
   const currentResultCounter = useSelector((state) => state.test.currentResultCounter);

   const testsState = {
      currentTest,
      currentResult,
      currentResultCounter
   }

   const onNextQuestionClick = (event) => {

      // вызывается на последнем вопросе
      if (currentQuestionIndex >= questionAmount - 1) {
         dispatch(
            addToCurrentResult({ selectedAnswerIndex, correctAnswerIndex }),
         );
         dispatch(addToResults(testsState)); // получает неактуальное состояние
         navigate(`/test/${testId}/result`); // currentTestResult будет очищен
         return;
      }

      dispatch(addToCurrentResult({ selectedAnswerIndex, correctAnswerIndex }));
      dispatch(nextQuestion({ selectedAnswerIndex }));
      setSelectedAnswerIndex(null);
   };

   return (
      <form className={styles.controls}>
         <div className={styles.answersList}>
            {answers.map((answer, i) => (
               <Answer
                  key={answer + i + currentQuestionIndex}
                  answer={answer}
                  id={"answer" + i + currentQuestionIndex}
                  value={i}
                  setSelectedAnswerIndex={setSelectedAnswerIndex}
               />
            ))}
         </div>
         <NextQuestionBtn
            onNextQuestionClick={onNextQuestionClick}
            selectedAnswerIndex={selectedAnswerIndex}
         />
      </form>
   );
};

export default AnswerList;
```

addToResults в resultSlice

```
addToResults(state, action) {
         const testsState = action.payload;
         console.log(testsState)

         const resultIndex = state.results.findIndex(
            (result) => result.testId === testsState.currentTest.id
         );
         const result = {
            testId: testsState.currentTest.id,
            resultCounter: testsState.currentResultCounter,
            results: testsState.currentResult,
         };

         if (resultIndex === -1) {
            state.results.push(result);
         } else {
            state.results[resultIndex] = result;
         }
      },
   },
```